# How to override FormControl method at RunTime?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm trying to make some kind of validation framework in **Dynamics AX 2009**.
And I need to override some FormControl methods at runtime.

For example this is **MyValidationTool** class:

```
void applyValidation(FormControl _control)
{
    _control.overideMethod("modified", this.validate());
}
```

So I can use it in any form object like this:

```
void init()
{
    MyValidationTool validationTool = new MyValidationTool();
    ;

    validationTool.applyValidation(userNameStringEdit);
}
```

Maybe I completely wrong at what I want. 
But I still will appreciate the answer of how I can override methods programmatically using X++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the tutorial form `tutorial_Form_AddControl`
What you have to do in short is create methods in the form of controlName_methodToOverride, e.g. `myTxt_validate`.
If you want to override the methods for runtime controls not directly on the form but on a separate object, take a look at the form's method `controlMethodOverloadObject` - with that method you can specify the object on which the methods of form controlName_methodToOverride will be invoked if possible.